# how to count number of 0's and 1's of a number without applying any functions like decimal to binary conversion?

Tags: python

I want to count the number of 0's and 1's in numbers from 0 to value.
(here in the code below value is 4,so count for 0,1,2,3).

If n and value are larger,it will give memory error due to large computation involved in decimal to binary computation.

```py
def decimalToBin(n):

    l=[]
    while(n>0):
        dig=n%2
        l.append(dig)
        n=n//2
    l.reverse()
    return l

def main():
    n=2

    value=2**n

    for i in range(value):

        l=decimalToBin(i)
        m=l.count(0)
        n=l.count(1)
        print(m,n)

main()
```

Is there any way to get to know the count of 0's and 1's without actually applying decimal to binary conversion..?

Comment: Please check your formatting.  You should post code that we can copy/paste and run immediately without having to set variables.

Comment: To make sure - you want the count of each binary digit in numbers between 0 (inclusive) and `2^n` (exclusive)?

Comment: Yes,You're right@Amadan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a math problem, not a programming problem per se - though it is a good exercise for a programmer.

Let's say n=4 and try to see if we notice anything interesting. So we're dealing with these numbers:

```
   0
   1
  10
  11
 100
 101
 110
 111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

The easiest observation is that the last bit toggles every row; the bit before it toggles every 2 rows; the next bit toggles every 4 rows, and the HSB toggles only once here (every 8 rows). The next thing you could note is that because of this, if we replaced the leading spaces with leading zeroes (i.e. if we made every row a 4-bit number), there would be exactly as many zeroes as ones. There would be 16 numbers (`2^n`), 4 bits each (`n`), so 64 bits in total (`2^n * n`), and 32 of them would be `1`, and the remaining 32 would be `0`. So the problem reduces to: how many leading spaces do we have?

Let's first consider the first row, as it is a bit anomalous - it is the only row that starts with a zero, because representing a number with no digits at all has proven to cause all sorts of problems. Let's pretend for now that zero is written as it logically would be - with no digits (and four leading spaces.) So, what do we have?

The last bit has just one leading space, the one in the "fixed" first row.
The second bit has two leading spaces.
The third bit has four leading spaces.
The MSB has eight leading spaces.

So we have the total of 1+2+4+8 leading spaces, which is `15` (`2^4 - 1`). We have to restore our first-row fix, and deduct one leading space (because we do want to write zero as `0`, and not as nothing), so the correct number of leading spaces is `2^n - 2`.

So we know that `2^n * n / 2` bits are `1`.
And we know that `2^n * n / 2 - (2^n - 2)` bits are `0`. This can be simplified: `2^n * (n / 2 - 1) + 2`

Lastly, note that Python writes exponentiation as `**`, not `^` (which is something different entirely). So...

```
num_of_ones = 2 ** n * n / 2
num_of_zeros = 2 ** n * (n / 2 - 1) + 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In a similar way could you please tell me how to find for individual numbers and print it? Like for n=2, value=4, i want to count and print the number of 1's and 0's first for 0 then count and print for 1 and so on. for eg. for 0 - it is num_of_ones=0 and num_of_zeros=1 ,     for 1- num_of_ones=1 and num_of_zeros=0 ,      for 2-  num_of_ones=1 and num_of_zeros=1 and    for 3-  num_of_ones=2 and num_of_zeros=0 .

Comment: There are no patterns for individual numbers - you would need to convert the number to binary.